# I use two interconnected ChainedForeignKey fields, but they don't. why?

Tags: django, django-ajax-selects, django-smart-selects

my problem:
I have three models. il (province), ilce (district) and mahalle (neighborhood).
I filter with smart-select. works smoothly in the entry of information. When I looked at the database, I saw that mahalle (neighborhood) data was recorded. but the mahalle (neighborhood) widget sounds empty.

my models:

```
class il(models.Model):
    adi = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ilce(models.Model):
    ill = models.ForeignKey(il, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adi = models.CharField(max_length=35)

class mahalle(models.Model):
    ilcee = models.ForeignKey(ilce, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adi = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    .......
    kurum_il = models.ForeignKey('il', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    kurum_ilce = ChainedForeignKey('ilce', chained_field="kurum_il", chained_model_field="ill", show_all=False, sort=False, null=True, blank=False)
    kurum_mahalle = ChainedForeignKey('mahalle', chained_field="kurum_ilce", chained_model_field='ilcee', show_all=False, sort=False, null=True, blank=False)
```

Does not appear on the Admin page even though I enter and save neighborhood information
[related screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2lSb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django-smart-selects](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects) looks long unmaintained with last release in 2018.

However there are few issues raised / discussed for it that may relate to your question, one of them [#237](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/pull/237). As a solution it has [this Pull Request](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/pull/260) with little change to `.js` file (actually it just comments out one line).

As it is not yet included in official release, you can apply these changes manually and provide new `.js` file to override package one:

- copy [chainedfk.js](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/blob/master/smart_selects/static/smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js) from master branch to your project
- place it at 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' path in your directory for [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders):

  - place inside `static` directory in your app and make this app appear *before* `smart_selects` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
  - or use same `static` directory or at another path by your preference but specify path to `static` directory in [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) (more preferred, not depend on order in `INSTALLED_APPS`)
- edit this file, apply [changes](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/pull/260/commits/8e634fa105cae491468ab34cf3993b49be9c422b) of [this Pull Request](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/pull/260) and any other changes of your choice.

Comment: manually updated chainedfk.js according to this PR, and my ChainedForeignKey field started rendering on admin update page. Thanks!